# Connecting to https with Socket

Tags: java, android, ssl

My app is based on Sockets, but regular Sockets, not SSLSockets. Do I have to change all of them to SSL sockets to be able connect to https server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change how the socket is created, by using the SSLSocketFactory, but you don't have to change all your datatypes from Socket to SSLSocket.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i think you have to change for SSL, you can try that :

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "clienttrust");
    SSLSocketFactory ssf = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    Socket s = ssf.createSocket("127.0.0.1", 8888);

    OutputStream outs = s.getOutputStream();
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(outs);
    InputStream ins = s.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));

    out.println("Hi,How are u!");
    out.println("");
    String line = null;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
    }

    in.close();
    out.close();
```

**it's from** : http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/HttpsSocketClient.htm

Hope it helps !

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.